# Количество строк и столбцов матриц

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from random import randint
n = int(input("Введите длину динамического массива : "))
a = [[randint(0,100) for i in range(n)]]
b = [[randint(0,100) for i in range(n)]]
s = 0
r = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        s += a[i][j]

for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(len(b[i])):
        s +=b[i][j]

print(s)

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        r-= a[i][j]

for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(len(b[i])):
        r -=b[i][j]

print(r)
```

Изначально нужно написать программу на питоне, которая запрашивает количество строк и столбцов у пользователя, а затем выводит сумму двух матриц и разность.
Помогите пожалуйста вывести правильно код для ввода строк и ввода столбцов. Правильна ли формула для вывода суммы и разности в коде?

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import randint

rows = int(input())
cols = int(input())

matrixA = [[randint(0, 100) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
matrixB = [[randint(0, 100) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]

sum_ = [[matrixA[i][j] + matrixB[i][j] for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
sub_ = [[matrixA[i][j] - matrixB[i][j] for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]

print(sum_)
print(sub_)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Место в раю тебе обеспечено. Последние два дня возился с этим на многих кибер форумах

Comment: @ИванПавлов, аха, да ладно =)